# How to broadcast the outer sum of elements of two vector of vectors?

Tags: arrays, julia, vectorization, tensor, array-broadcasting

I have two `Matrix{Vector{}}`, say `A` and `B`, of the same sizes. I want to get a `Matrix{Matrix{}}`, `M`, such that each element is an outer sum of each element of `A` and `B`, i.e.

`M[i, j][k, l] = A[i, j][k] + B[i, j][l]`.

How could I vectorize the above operation?

Example case:

```
A=[[[1, 2]] [[3, 4]] ; [[5, 6]] [[7, 8]]]
2×2 Matrix{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2]  [3, 4]
 [5, 6]  [7, 8]
```

```
B=[[[11, 21]] [[13, 44]] ; [[25, 61]] [[27, 28]]]
2×2 Matrix{Vector{Int64}}:
 [11, 21]  [13, 44]
 [25, 61]  [27, 28]
```

```
size(A)==size(B)
true
```

```
M=[A[i, j] .+ B[i, j]' for i in 1:size(A)[1], j in 1:size(A)[2]]
2×2 Matrix{Matrix{Int64}}:
 [12 22; 13 23]  [16 47; 17 48]
 [30 66; 31 67]  [34 35; 35 36]
```

I would love to find a way for avoiding the `for` loop, since in my use case, `A` and `B` are huge matrices! I also tried `A .+ adjoint.(B)` but this throws an error message:

`ERROR: DimensionMismatch: dimensions must match: a has dims (Base.OneTo(1), Base.OneTo(2)), b has dims (Base.OneTo(2),), mismatch at 1`.

I found a workaround using the [TensorCast](https://github.com/mcabbott/TensorCast.jl) package which looks something like

```
@cast MCast[i, j][k, l] := A[i, j][k] + B[i, j][l];

julia> MCast = collect(MCast);

julia> MCast
2×2 Matrix{SubArray{Int64, 2, Array{Int64, 4}, Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, Int64, Int64}, true}}:
 [12 22; 13 23]  [16 47; 17 48]
 [30 66; 31 67]  [34 35; 35 36]
```

This does work, but I was wondering if there exists a more elegant way of doing this, preferably in native Julia.

Comment: Re TensorCast, `MCast = collect(MCast)` is doing nothing. If you want a Matrix{Matrix{Int}} instead of views, SubArray, you can write `@cast MCast[i, j][k, l] |= ...`.

Comment: @AnjishnuBose It doesn't matter for the loop how large the matrices are. Note that the your comprehension is faster and more memory efficient than the accepted answer using `map`. (In case you were not aware, loops are fast in Julia, and is normally the fastest solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
julia> map(.+, A, adjoint.(B))
2×2 Matrix{Matrix{Int64}}:
 [12 22; 13 23]  [16 47; 17 48]
 [30 66; 31 67]  [34 35; 35 36]
```

is what I got so far.

Slight improvement:

```
using MappedArrays

map(.+, A, mappedarray(adjoint,B))
```

(does not materialize `adjoint.(B)`)

Answer (score 0):

Using an array comprehension is more efficient than using `map` with `.+`, since it avoids an unnecessary allocation. But you can write your comprehension more concise and elegant, and more safe. Indexing over `1:size(A)[1]` etc. is not seen as safe, since not all arrays have indices like that.

Here are three alternatives:

```
[A[i, j] .+ B[i, j]' for i in axes(A, 1), j in axes(A, 2)]
[A[i] .+ B[i]' for i in CartesianIndices(A)]
[a .+ b' for (a, b) in zip(A, B)]
```

Remember, loops are fast in Julia.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, will keep that in mind. However, I do find that both the mapped method and TensorCast method are much faster, am I doing something wrong? I am just checking for some artificially large A and B in the REPL.

Comment: I haven't tried TensorCast, but using BenchmarkTools.jl I find that the comprehension is consistently faster than `map`, by maybe 5% (from memory, now). My guess is that your results are due to benchmarking artefacts.

Comment: On second thought, perhaps they do scale differently with size. Still, test it properly with BenchmarkTools.jl